# Getting " ValueError: No route found for path 'socket/order' ' " in Django Channels when trying to connect with Angular frontend

Tags: python, django, angular, websocket, django-channels

I am trying Django Channels for the first time. I am trying to connect it with an existing Angular frontend application. But for some reason the routing isn't working I cannot figure out why. I have written the codes exactly how the Django Channels documentation instructs to.

The error message goes as such -

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 10, 2023 - 15:34:50
Django version 4.1.3, using settings 'BrokerBackEnd.settings'
Starting ASGI/Daphne version 4.0.0 development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /socket/order [127.0.0.1:63732]
HTTP GET /orders/ 200 [0.07, 127.0.0.1:63731]
Exception inside application: No route found for path 'socket/order'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Neha\Documents\broker-back-end-py\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 101, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Neha\Documents\broker-back-end-py\env\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\Neha\Documents\broker-back-end-py\env\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 134, in __call__
    raise ValueError("No route found for path %r." % path)
ValueError: No route found for path 'socket/order'.
WebSocket DISCONNECT /socket/order [127.0.0.1:63732]
```

Would really appreciate if anyone could suggest anything. Thank you.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'channels',
    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',

    'Orders'
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'BrokerBackEnd.asgi.application'
```

**asgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
import Orders.routing as route

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'BrokerBackEnd.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    
    'websocket': URLRouter(
            route.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
})
```

**consumer.py**

```
class OrderConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()
    
    def receive(self, text_data=None, bytes_data=None):
        self.send(text_data="Message = " + text_data)
    
    def disconnect(self, code):
        return super().disconnect(code)
```

**routing.py**

```
from django.urls import re_path
from .consumer import OrderConsumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"socket/order/", OrderConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

This is the frontend code -

```
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { EMPTY, Observable } from "rxjs";
import { webSocket, WebSocketSubject } from 'rxjs/webSocket';
import { Order } from './order.model';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OrderWebSocketService {

    myWebSocket: WebSocketSubject<Order> = webSocket('ws://localhost:8000/socket/order');

    constructor(private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

    public connect(): Observable<Order> {
        return this.myWebSocket.asObservable().pipe(
            map((obj) => obj),
            catchError((error) => this.errorHandler(error))
        );
    }

    public close(): void {
        this.myWebSocket.complete();
    }

    errorHandler(e: any): Observable<any> {
        this.showMessage('Something wrong happened with websocket!', true);
        return EMPTY;
    }

    showMessage(msg: string, isError: boolean = false): void {
        this.snackBar.open(msg, 'X', {
            duration: 3000,
            horizontalPosition: "right",
            verticalPosition: "top",
            panelClass: isError ? ['msg-error'] : ['msg-success']
        });
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try changing `'ws://localhost:8000/socket/order'` to `'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/socket/order'` in your front-end.  I don't know Angular, but it looks like you're hard-coding 'localhost' into the websocket url, but localhost must be looked up, and it is *not* always the same as '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: @raphael That didn't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: It could just be the forward slash at the end.  Try `'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/socket/order/'`.  But if that doesn't work, then I'm sorry, I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: Glad you got it to work!